# How to save a file that contains 2 QMap datas in Qt?

Tags: qt, qmap

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Serialization with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570679/serialization-with-qt)

I have 2 datas which type is QMap:

1.QMap novel;
    QString tempChapter;
    QString tempStory;

2.QMap combo;
    int tempInd;
    QString tempChap;

my question is:
How can I save these 2 Datas into a single file??
And if it's successfully saved, how can I load these 2 datas?
Please insert the code too because I'm a beginner C++ programmer and dont know much about OOP,,
please answer this ASAP! Thank you very much! :)

Comment: This is not a homework assignment, is it? :)

Comment: nope, it's for a Nokia Qt Programming Competition :)
*its only for a small scale region, though..*

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570679/serialization-with-qt/2571212#2571212

Answer (score 2):

All of the basic collections in qt are supported by [QDataStream](http://doc.trolltech.com/4.6/qdatastream.html) check for support in the [QMap](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.6/qmap.html) docs, as you are only storing other basic qt types and ints you should be ok

Comment: He, didn't know that. Much better than my idea:) +1

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you will have to think of a format to store your data in yourself. I would suggest to read something about [serialization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Serialization). Read [this](http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq-lite/serialization.html) for some general information about serialization in C++.

Comment: thanks for always answering my questions :)
but in the end, i still dont get this QMap thing,, lol
guess i have to learn about Qt more,,

Comment: It's not really a Qt thing. Just find a way to represent a map as text. You could, for example, write one line per key/value pair and separate each pair by some special character(s). This is really easy to write and parse.