# how to save qundocommand to file and reload it?

Tags: qt, undo-redo

I am using qt's undo framework , which use qundocommand to do some application support undo. 
Is there an easy way I can use to save those qundocommand to a file and reload it?

Answer (score 2):

There's no built-in way. I don't think it's very common to save the undo stack between sessions. You'll have to serialize the commands yourself by iterating through the commands on the stack, and saving each one's unique data using [QDataStream](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qdatastream.html). It might look something like this:

```
...
dataStream << undoStack->count(); // store number of commands

for (int i = 0; i < undoStack->count(); i++)
{
    // store each command's unique information
    dataStream << undoStack->command(i)->someMemberVariable;
}
...
```

Then you would use QDataStream again to deserialize the data back into QUndoCommands.

You can use [QFile](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qfile.html) to handle the file management.

Comment: There are other reasons for writing to disk - if you have 500 undo commands it will ramp up the memory usage.

Answer (score 1):

Use Qt's serialization as described here:

[Serialization with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570679/serialization-with-qt)

Then within your QUndoCommands you can use a temp file to write the data to it:

http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtemporaryfile.html

However this might cause you an issue since each file is kept open and so on some platforms (Linux) you may run out of open file handles.

To combat this you'd have to create some other factory type object which handles your commands - then this could pass in a reference to a QTemporaryFile automatically. This factory/QUndoCommand care taker object must have the same life time as the QUndoCommands. If not then the temp file will be removed from disk and your QUndoCommands will break.

The other thing you can do is use QUndoCommand as a proxy to your real undo command - this means you can save quite a bit of memory since when your undo command is saved to file you can delete the internal pointer/set it to null. Then restore it later.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a PyQt solution for serializing/pickling QUndoCommands. The tricky part was getting the parent to call `__init__` first, then the children. This method relies on all the children's `__setstate__` to be called before the parent's, which happens upon pickling as children are returned in the parent's `__getstate__`.

```py
class UndoCommand(QUndoCommand):
    """
    For pickling
    """
    def __init__(self, text, parent=None):
        QUndoCommand.__init__(self, text, parent)
        self.__parent = parent
        self.__initialized = True

        # defined and initialized in __setstate__
        # self.__child_states = {}

    def __getstate__(self):
        return {
            **{k: v for k, v in self.__dict__.items()},
            '_UndoCommand__initialized': False,
            '_UndoCommand__text': self.text(),
            '_UndoCommand__children':
                [self.child(i) for i in range(self.childCount())]
        }

    def __setstate__(self, state):
        if hasattr(self, '_UndoCommand__initialized') and \
                self.__initialized:
            return

        text = state['_UndoCommand__text']
        parent = state['_UndoCommand__parent']  # type: UndoCommand

        if parent is not None and \
                (not hasattr(parent, '_UndoCommand__initialized') or
                 not parent.__initialized):
            # will be initialized in parent's __setstate__
            if not hasattr(parent, '_UndoCommand__child_states'):
                setattr(parent, '_UndoCommand__child_states', {})
            parent.__child_states[self] = state
            return

        # init must be called on unpickle-time to recreate Qt object
        UndoCommand.__init__(self, text, parent)
        for child in state['_UndoCommand__children']:
            child.__setstate__(self.__child_states[child])

        self.__dict__ = {k: v for k, v in state.items()}

    @staticmethod
    def from_QUndoCommand(qc: QUndoCommand, parent=None):
        if type(qc) == QUndoCommand:
            qc.__class__ = UndoCommand
            qc.__initialized = True

        qc.__parent = parent

        children = [qc.child(i) for i in range(qc.childCount())]
        for child in children:
            UndoCommand.from_QUndoCommand(child, parent=qc)

        return qc
```