# QTcpSocket write an struct of data

Tags: c++, qt, struct, qtcpsocket

I used to send an struct with C++ sockets, and now I'm trying to use QTcpSockets instead. This is the struct:

```
const unsigned int uiMessageSize = 4;
    typedef struct {
        unsigned char uc_stx;
        unsigned char uc_add;
        unsigned char uc_state;
        unsigned char uc_eot;
        unsigned char uc_unused_padding[1024];
    } st_message;
```

So then, for writing I used to call `write(sockfd, &messageToSend, uiMessagePcToMastSize);`

Now I'm trying with: `socket->write(&messageToSend, uiMessagePcToMastSize);` and doesn't work: **no matching function for call to ‘QTcpSocket::write(mastControl::st_messagePcToMast*, const unsigned int&)**.

I have searched more info, and looks like I should convert the struct to a QDataStrem, or just a QByteArray. I don't really know how to del with this.

Any help?

Comment: this link might help, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570679/serialization-with-qt

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the [documentation](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qiodevice.html#write) shows that the write function is overloaded with 1 function being `qint64 QIODevice::write ( const char * data, qint64 maxSize )`, so casting to `const char*` should be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Just add a toQBytearray and add a constructor in the struct where you split the bytearray to the struct where you convert the data . Put a splitvalue Like # or ; between the datasets and when you receive the data on your server just use the above mentioned constructor