# Best way to write a custom class to a file using qt

Tags: qt, serialization, qfile, qiodevice

Hey all (out there :).
Which way is the best for writing a custom class to a file in Qt?
Thank you in advance.
Matthias

Comment: possible duplicate of [Serialization with Qt](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570679/serialization-with-qt).Look at this post, it may contain additional information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: Question has been already asked. [Serialization with Qt](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2570679/serialization-with-qt)

The best way is to serialize using [QDataStream](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/qdatastream.html#details). For a given class `MyClass`, you need to define new stream operators

```
QDataStream &operator<<(QDataStream &, const MyClass &);
QDataStream &operator>>(QDataStream &, MyClass &);
```

`QDataStream` is already capable of writing several Qt classes, mostly collections and other convenients classes like `QImage`, etc.... Note that you cannot serialize any subclass of `QObject`. There are reasons :), but limit yourself to the explanation that `QObject` itself doesn't provide neither copy constructors nor in\out stream functions like the one above.

Note that if your custom class derive a class already providing serialization, you need to call the stream operators for this superclass (the same principle as calling the constructor of the superclass when constructing the subclass).

Comment: it makes sense, that it isn't possible to serialize QOBject subclasses... :) that would cause a great huddle :D